# How can I support the "time-sensitive" function

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

How can I support the "time-sensitive" choose on iOS15 device
[![just like this][1]]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkjNf.png

Comment: I can't embed image because I have not enough reputation

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the **Capability** for your project in Xcode.

Select the Target, click the `+ Capability` button, and select `Time Sensitive Notifications`:

[image]

You may want to watch this video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10091/